# Clearing a series and keep others in JFreeChart

Tags: time-series, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to create a chart that has 6 TimeSeries in it.
**Problem**: When I call `.clear()` on one of those series all others get hidden:

```
    this.Series1.clear();
```

**Question**: What should I do to clear a series without others disappear?

Before calling `.clear()` on the "Red" series.
[image]

After calling `.clear()` on the "Red" series.
[image]

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod: I tried to make it sscce.

Comment: No, one line is not at [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the expected result using either of these:

```
dataset.removeSeries(0);
dataset.getSeries(0).clear();
```

You may need to verify that each `TimeSeries` is a distinct instance.